# java GUI application weird delay issue?

Tags: java

I have a small application having a javax.swing.Timer with very small delay, it expresses a moving a road, it works on all PCs as expected, on my pc it works in a very strange manner.

when i open it alone it works with wrong delay or flickers, but if i loaded some specific applications with it (applications not related to netbeans) it works as expected, what may cause such a strange thing ?

the best description of the problem is this short video (30 seconds):
[the video](https://youtu.be/_yuKOmOjwGk)